# Freeradius doesn't see its WAP-Client

Tags: debian, hostapd, radius, 802.1x, freeradius

I have Freeradius v.3 Server and WAccessPoint (hostapd), both on the same machine (localhost) Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 installed.

I tested my connection firstly without freeradius -> I can connect to WAP and use Internet through NAS and MASQUERADE.

When I want to start Authentication with Freeradius, I change WAP-PSK to WAP-EAP, add some lines for RADIUS-SERVER in hostapd.conf and start freeradius -X (in debug mode), but there are no logs, when I try to connect through AP.

Whether connection is successful or not, it should be logged and debugged by each connection to Freeradius, but I see nothing, what means, that my Client and Freeradius doesn't recognize each other. Here are my settings:

hostapd.conf:

```
...
own_ip_addr=127.0.0.1
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wmm_enabled=1
wpa=2
channel=1
auth_algs=1
auth_server_addr=127.0.0.1
auth_server_port=1812
auth_server_shared_secret=secret 
...
```

/etc/freeradius/clients.conf

```
client localhost {
ipaddr=127.0.0.1
secret=secret
require_message_authenticator = yes
}
```

I've also tried to create a new client in client.conf with ipaddr of my WAP INTERFACE, but I doesn't work also.

UPDATE1:

freeradius -v:

```
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.11, for host x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

netstat -alnp | grep 1812:

```
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:1812 0.0.0.0:*
udp 0 0 127.0.0.1:25868 127.0.0.1:1812 ESTABLISHED 1191/hostapd
```

UPDATE2: server config file:

```
server {
listen {
    type = auth
    port = 1812
    ipaddr = *
}
authorize {
    preprocess
    eap {
            ok = return
    }
    expiration
    logintime
}
authenticate {
    eap
}
preacct {
    preprocess
    acct_unique
    suffix
    files
}
accounting {
    detail
    # unix
    radutmp
    # exec
    attr_filter.accounting_response
}
session {
    radutmp
}
post-auth {
    # exec
    Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
            attr_filter.access_reject
    }
}
pre-proxy {

}
post-proxy {
    eap
}
```

}

UPDATE3:

freeradius -X:

```
    Server was built with: 
  accounting               : yes
  authentication           : yes
  ascend-binary-attributes : yes
  coa                      : yes
  control-socket           : yes
  detail                   : yes
  dhcp                     : yes
  dynamic-clients          : yes
  osfc2                    : no
  proxy                    : yes
  regex-pcre               : no
  regex-posix              : yes
  regex-posix-extended     : yes
  session-management       : yes
  stats                    : yes
  tcp                      : yes
  threads                  : yes
  tls                      : yes
  unlang                   : yes
  vmps                     : yes
  developer                : no
Server core libs:
  freeradius-server        : 3.0.11
  talloc                   : 2.0.*
  ssl                      : 1.0.2g release
Endianness:
  little
Compilation flags:
  cppflags : -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
  cflags   : -I/build/freeradius-G88Mfz/freeradius-3.0.11 -I/build/freeradius-G88Mfz/freeradius-3.0.11/src -include /build/freeradius-G88Mfz/freeradius-3.0.11/src/freeradius-devel/autoconf.h -include /build/freeradius-G88Mfz/freeradius-3.0.11/src/freeradius-devel/build.h -include /build/freeradius-G88Mfz/freeradius-3.0.11/src/freeradius-devel/features.h -include /build/freeradius-G88Mfz/freeradius-3.0.11/src/freeradius-devel/radpaths.h -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O2 -Wall -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -DNDEBUG -DIS_MODULE=1
  ldflags  :  -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro
  libs     : -lcrypto -lssl -ltalloc -lcap -lnsl -lresolv -ldl -lpthread -lreadline

Copyright (C) 1999-2016 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE
You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
GNU General Public License
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYRIGHT
Starting - reading configuration files ...
including dictionary file /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary
including dictionary file /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary.dhcp
including dictionary file /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary.vqp
including dictionary file /etc/freeradius/dictionary
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/clients.conf
including files in directory /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/detail
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/utf8
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/linelog
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/realm
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/echo
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/radutmp
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/exec
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/unpack
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/mschap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/replicate
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/cache_eap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/pap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/passwd
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/files
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/logintime
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/unix
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/soh
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/expiration
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/sradutmp
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/chap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/preprocess
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/expr
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/attr_filter
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/dynamic_clients
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/digest
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/eap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/detail.log
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/ntlm_auth
including files in directory /etc/freeradius/policy.d/
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/policy.d/canonicalization
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/policy.d/filter
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/policy.d/accounting
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/policy.d/cui
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/policy.d/dhcp
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/policy.d/operator-name
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/policy.d/eap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/policy.d/abfab-tr
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/policy.d/debug
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/policy.d/control
including files in directory /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/mynetwork
main {
 security {
    user = "freerad"
    group = "freerad"
    allow_core_dumps = no
 }
    name = "freeradius"
    prefix = "/usr"
    localstatedir = "/var"
    logdir = "/var/log/freeradius"
    run_dir = "/var/run/freeradius"
}
main {
    name = "freeradius"
    prefix = "/usr"
    localstatedir = "/var"
    sbindir = "/usr/sbin"
    logdir = "/var/log/freeradius"
    run_dir = "/var/run/freeradius"
    libdir = "/usr/lib/freeradius"
    radacctdir = "/var/log/freeradius/radacct"
    hostname_lookups = no
    max_request_time = 30
    cleanup_delay = 5
    max_requests = 16384
    pidfile = "/var/run/freeradius/freeradius.pid"
    checkrad = "/usr/sbin/checkrad"
    debug_level = 0
    proxy_requests = no
 log {
    stripped_names = no
    auth = yes
    auth_badpass = no
    auth_goodpass = no
    colourise = yes
    msg_denied = "You are already logged in - access denied"
 }
 resources {
 }
 security {
    max_attributes = 200
    reject_delay = 1.000000
    status_server = yes
 }
}
radiusd: #### Loading Realms and Home Servers ####
radiusd: #### Loading Clients ####
 client myclient {
    ipaddr = 10.0.0.1
    require_message_authenticator = yes
    secret = <<< secret >>>
  limit {
    max_connections = 16
    lifetime = 0
    idle_timeout = 30
  }
 }
 client localhost {
    ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
    require_message_authenticator = no
    secret = <<< secret >>>
    nas_type = "other"
    proto = "*"
  limit {
    max_connections = 16
    lifetime = 0
    idle_timeout = 30
  }
 }
 client localhost_ipv6 {
    ipv6addr = ::1
    require_message_authenticator = no
    secret = <<< secret >>>
  limit {
    max_connections = 16
    lifetime = 0
    idle_timeout = 30
  }
 }
Debugger not attached
 # Creating Auth-Type = eap
radiusd: #### Instantiating modules ####
 modules {
  # Loaded module rlm_detail
  # Loading module "detail" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/detail
  detail {
    filename = "/var/log/freeradius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/detail-%Y%m%d"
    header = "%t"
    permissions = 384
    locking = no
    escape_filenames = no
    log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_utf8
  # Loading module "utf8" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/utf8
  # Loaded module rlm_linelog
  # Loading module "linelog" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/linelog
  linelog {
    filename = "/var/log/freeradius/linelog"
    escape_filenames = no
    syslog_severity = "info"
    permissions = 384
    format = "This is a log message for %{User-Name}"
    reference = "messages.%{%{reply:Packet-Type}:-default}"
  }
  # Loading module "log_accounting" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/linelog
  linelog log_accounting {
    filename = "/var/log/freeradius/linelog-accounting"
    escape_filenames = no
    syslog_severity = "info"
    permissions = 384
    format = ""
    reference = "Accounting-Request.%{%{Acct-Status-Type}:-unknown}"
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_realm
  # Loading module "IPASS" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/realm
  realm IPASS {
    format = "prefix"
    delimiter = "/"
    ignore_default = no
    ignore_null = no
  }
  # Loading module "suffix" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/realm
  realm suffix {
    format = "suffix"
    delimiter = "@"
    ignore_default = no
    ignore_null = no
  }
  # Loading module "realmpercent" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/realm
  realm realmpercent {
    format = "suffix"
    delimiter = "%"
    ignore_default = no
    ignore_null = no
  }
  # Loading module "ntdomain" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/realm
  realm ntdomain {
    format = "prefix"
    delimiter = "\\"
    ignore_default = no
    ignore_null = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_exec
  # Loading module "echo" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/echo
  exec echo {
    wait = yes
    program = "/bin/echo %{User-Name}"
    input_pairs = "request"
    output_pairs = "reply"
    shell_escape = yes
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_radutmp
  # Loading module "radutmp" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/radutmp
  radutmp {
    filename = "/var/log/freeradius/radutmp"
    username = "%{User-Name}"
    case_sensitive = yes
    check_with_nas = yes
    permissions = 384
    caller_id = yes
  }
  # Loading module "exec" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/exec
  exec {
    wait = no
    input_pairs = "request"
    shell_escape = yes
    timeout = 10
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_unpack
  # Loading module "unpack" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/unpack
  # Loaded module rlm_mschap
  # Loading module "mschap" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/mschap
  mschap {
    use_mppe = yes
    require_encryption = no
    require_strong = no
    with_ntdomain_hack = yes
   passchange {
   }
    allow_retry = yes
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_replicate
  # Loading module "replicate" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/replicate
  # Loaded module rlm_cache
  # Loading module "cache_eap" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/cache_eap
  cache cache_eap {
    driver = "rlm_cache_rbtree"
    key = "%{%{control:State}:-%{%{reply:State}:-%{State}}}"
    ttl = 15
    max_entries = 0
    epoch = 0
    add_stats = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_pap
  # Loading module "pap" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/pap
  pap {
    normalise = yes
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_passwd
  # Loading module "etc_passwd" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/passwd
  passwd etc_passwd {
    filename = "/etc/passwd"
    format = "*User-Name:Crypt-Password:"
    delimiter = ":"
    ignore_nislike = no
    ignore_empty = yes
    allow_multiple_keys = no
    hash_size = 100
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_files
  # Loading module "files" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/files
  files {
    filename = "/etc/freeradius/mods-config/files/authorize"
    acctusersfile = "/etc/freeradius/mods-config/files/accounting"
    preproxy_usersfile = "/etc/freeradius/mods-config/files/pre-proxy"
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_logintime
  # Loading module "logintime" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/logintime
  logintime {
    minimum_timeout = 60
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_unix
  # Loading module "unix" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/unix
  unix {
    radwtmp = "/var/log/freeradius/radwtmp"
  }
Creating attribute Unix-Group
  # Loaded module rlm_soh
  # Loading module "soh" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/soh
  soh {
    dhcp = yes
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_expiration
  # Loading module "expiration" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/expiration
  # Loading module "sradutmp" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/sradutmp
  radutmp sradutmp {
    filename = "/var/log/freeradius/sradutmp"
    username = "%{User-Name}"
    case_sensitive = yes
    check_with_nas = yes
    permissions = 420
    caller_id = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_chap
  # Loading module "chap" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/chap
  # Loaded module rlm_preprocess
  # Loading module "preprocess" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/preprocess
  preprocess {
    huntgroups = "/etc/freeradius/mods-config/preprocess/huntgroups"
    hints = "/etc/freeradius/mods-config/preprocess/hints"
    with_ascend_hack = no
    ascend_channels_per_line = 23
    with_ntdomain_hack = no
    with_specialix_jetstream_hack = no
    with_cisco_vsa_hack = no
    with_alvarion_vsa_hack = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_expr
  # Loading module "expr" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/expr
  expr {
    safe_characters = "@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.-_: /äéöüàâæçèéêëîïôœùûüaÿÄÉÖÜßÀÂÆÇÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸ"
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_attr_filter
  # Loading module "attr_filter.post-proxy" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.post-proxy {
    filename = "/etc/freeradius/mods-config/attr_filter/post-proxy"
    key = "%{Realm}"
    relaxed = no
  }
  # Loading module "attr_filter.pre-proxy" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.pre-proxy {
    filename = "/etc/freeradius/mods-config/attr_filter/pre-proxy"
    key = "%{Realm}"
    relaxed = no
  }
  # Loading module "attr_filter.access_reject" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.access_reject {
    filename = "/etc/freeradius/mods-config/attr_filter/access_reject"
    key = "%{User-Name}"
    relaxed = no
  }
  # Loading module "attr_filter.access_challenge" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.access_challenge {
    filename = "/etc/freeradius/mods-config/attr_filter/access_challenge"
    key = "%{User-Name}"
    relaxed = no
  }
  # Loading module "attr_filter.accounting_response" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.accounting_response {
    filename = "/etc/freeradius/mods-config/attr_filter/accounting_response"
    key = "%{User-Name}"
    relaxed = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_dynamic_clients
  # Loading module "dynamic_clients" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/dynamic_clients
  # Loaded module rlm_digest
  # Loading module "digest" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/digest
  # Loaded module rlm_eap
  # Loading module "eap" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/eap
  eap {
    default_eap_type = "tls"
    timer_expire = 60
    ignore_unknown_eap_types = no
    cisco_accounting_username_bug = no
    max_sessions = 4096
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_always
  # Loading module "reject" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  always reject {
    rcode = "reject"
    simulcount = 0
    mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "fail" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  always fail {
    rcode = "fail"
    simulcount = 0
    mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "ok" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  always ok {
    rcode = "ok"
    simulcount = 0
    mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "handled" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  always handled {
    rcode = "handled"
    simulcount = 0
    mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "invalid" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  always invalid {
    rcode = "invalid"
    simulcount = 0
    mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "userlock" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  always userlock {
    rcode = "userlock"
    simulcount = 0
    mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "notfound" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  always notfound {
    rcode = "notfound"
    simulcount = 0
    mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "noop" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  always noop {
    rcode = "noop"
    simulcount = 0
    mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "updated" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  always updated {
    rcode = "updated"
    simulcount = 0
    mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "auth_log" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/detail.log
  detail auth_log {
    filename = "/var/log/freeradius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/auth-detail-%Y%m%d"
    header = "%t"
    permissions = 384
    locking = no
    escape_filenames = no
    log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loading module "reply_log" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/detail.log
  detail reply_log {
    filename = "/var/log/freeradius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/reply-detail-%Y%m%d"
    header = "%t"
    permissions = 384
    locking = no
    escape_filenames = no
    log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loading module "pre_proxy_log" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/detail.log
  detail pre_proxy_log {
    filename = "/var/log/freeradius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/pre-proxy-detail-%Y%m%d"
    header = "%t"
    permissions = 384
    locking = no
    escape_filenames = no
    log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loading module "post_proxy_log" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/detail.log
  detail post_proxy_log {
    filename = "/var/log/freeradius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/post-proxy-detail-%Y%m%d"
    header = "%t"
    permissions = 384
    locking = no
    escape_filenames = no
    log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loading module "ntlm_auth" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/ntlm_auth
  exec ntlm_auth {
    wait = yes
    program = "/path/to/ntlm_auth --request-nt-key --domain=MYDOMAIN --username=%{mschap:User-Name} --password=%{User-Password}"
    shell_escape = yes
  }
  instantiate {
  }
  # Instantiating module "detail" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/detail
  # Instantiating module "linelog" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/linelog
  # Instantiating module "log_accounting" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/linelog
  # Instantiating module "IPASS" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/realm
  # Instantiating module "suffix" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/realm
  # Instantiating module "realmpercent" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/realm
  # Instantiating module "ntdomain" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/realm
  # Instantiating module "mschap" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/mschap
rlm_mschap (mschap): using internal authentication
  # Instantiating module "cache_eap" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/cache_eap
rlm_cache (cache_eap): Driver rlm_cache_rbtree (module rlm_cache_rbtree) loaded and linked
  # Instantiating module "pap" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/pap
  # Instantiating module "etc_passwd" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/passwd
rlm_passwd: nfields: 3 keyfield 0(User-Name) listable: no
  # Instantiating module "files" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/files
reading pairlist file /etc/freeradius/mods-config/files/authorize
reading pairlist file /etc/freeradius/mods-config/files/accounting
reading pairlist file /etc/freeradius/mods-config/files/pre-proxy
  # Instantiating module "logintime" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/logintime
  # Instantiating module "expiration" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/expiration
  # Instantiating module "preprocess" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/preprocess
reading pairlist file /etc/freeradius/mods-config/preprocess/huntgroups
reading pairlist file /etc/freeradius/mods-config/preprocess/hints
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.post-proxy" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/freeradius/mods-config/attr_filter/post-proxy
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.pre-proxy" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/freeradius/mods-config/attr_filter/pre-proxy
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.access_reject" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/freeradius/mods-config/attr_filter/access_reject
[/etc/freeradius/mods-config/attr_filter/access_reject]:11 Check item "FreeRADIUS-Response-Delay"   found in filter list for realm "DEFAULT". 
[/etc/freeradius/mods-config/attr_filter/access_reject]:11 Check item "FreeRADIUS-Response-Delay-USec"  found in filter list for realm "DEFAULT". 
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.access_challenge" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/freeradius/mods-config/attr_filter/access_challenge
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.accounting_response" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/freeradius/mods-config/attr_filter/accounting_response
  # Instantiating module "eap" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/eap
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_md5
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_leap
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_tls
   tls {
    tls = "tls-common"
   }
   tls-config tls-common {
    verify_depth = 0
    ca_path = "/etc/freeradius/certs"
    pem_file_type = yes
    private_key_file = "/etc/freeradius/certs/server.key"
    certificate_file = "/etc/freeradius/certs/server.pem"
    ca_file = "/etc/freeradius/certs/ca.pem"
    private_key_password = <<< secret >>>
    dh_file = "/etc/freeradius/certs/dh"
    random_file = "/dev/urandom"
    fragment_size = 1024
    include_length = yes
    auto_chain = yes
    check_crl = no
    check_all_crl = no
    cipher_list = "HIGH"
    ecdh_curve = "prime256v1"
    cache {
        enable = no
        lifetime = 24
        max_entries = 255
    }
    verify {
        skip_if_ocsp_ok = no
        tmpdir = "/tmp/radiusd"
        client = "/usr/bin/openssl verify -CApath /etc/freeradius/certs %{TLS-Client-Cert-Filename}"
    }
    ocsp {
        enable = no
        override_cert_url = yes
        url = "http://127.0.0.1/ocsp/"
        use_nonce = yes
        timeout = 0
        softfail = no
    }
   }
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_ttls
   ttls {
    tls = "tls-common"
    default_eap_type = "md5"
    copy_request_to_tunnel = no
    use_tunneled_reply = no
    virtual_server = "inner-tunnel"
    include_length = yes
    require_client_cert = no
   }
tls: Using cached TLS configuration from previous invocation
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_peap
   peap {
    tls = "tls-common"
    default_eap_type = "mschapv2"
    copy_request_to_tunnel = no
    use_tunneled_reply = no
    proxy_tunneled_request_as_eap = yes
    virtual_server = "inner-tunnel"
    soh = no
    require_client_cert = no
   }
tls: Using cached TLS configuration from previous invocation
  # Instantiating module "reject" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "fail" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "ok" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "handled" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "invalid" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "userlock" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "notfound" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "noop" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "updated" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "auth_log" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/detail.log
rlm_detail (auth_log): 'User-Password' suppressed, will not appear in detail output
  # Instantiating module "reply_log" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/detail.log
  # Instantiating module "pre_proxy_log" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/detail.log
  # Instantiating module "post_proxy_log" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/detail.log
 } # modules
radiusd: #### Loading Virtual Servers ####
server { # from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/mynetwork
 # Loading authenticate {...}
 # Loading authorize {...}
 # Loading preacct {...}
 # Loading accounting {...}
 # Loading session {...}
 # Loading post-auth {...}
} # server
radiusd: #### Opening IP addresses and Ports ####
listen {
    type = "auth"
    ipaddr = *
    port = 1812
}
Listening on auth address * port 1812
Ready to process requests
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend your localhost entry in your `/etc/freeradius/clients.conf` to be:

```
client localhost {
    ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
    secret      = secret
    require_message_authenticator = no
    nas_type     = other
}
```

`nas_type` usually is `cisco`, `livingston` or `other`.

CHECK ALSO your hostapd.conf: you should also set `ieee8021x=1`

As for `require_message_authenticator` it is more useful to send CoA/disconnect messages, and for it to be configured you need `radius_das_require_message_authenticator=1` in `hostapd.conf`. I would do without it [for now].

To run `freeradius -X` for debugging, you also need to stop the `freeradius` daemon, as from your netstat command, we can see 1812 is listening, and as such the service is running; debugging it assumes you are booting it anew in a single thread daemon.

Freeradius will boot upon until "Listening ...Ready to process requests". The real fun begins here, that everything after that is for debugging the transactions authenticating the Wifi clients. At any time, you can leave with ^C, and if you want to get the service up, you can launch the service again.

It should be noted that the `password`/secret in clients.conf should be the same used for debugging commands, or in hostpad.conf. Otherwise freeradius will reject any packets with other secret.

As for the debugging commands we used to debug FreeRadius requests, for the benefit of others:

```
echo "Message-Authenticator = 0x00,FreeRADIUS-Statistics-Type = 31" | radclient localhost:18121 status adminsecret
```

This one checks the status, but you have to have the status vhost active.

and:

```
echo "User-Name=test,User-Password=mypass,Framed-Protocol=PPP " | /usr/local/bin/radclient localhost:1812 auth secret
```

As for the future, after you get a little more confortable with Freeradius and if this setup is to be used in production, I would advise to get and compile the current 3.0.13 from github, as there are countless bug fixes.

Comment: odd. what happens when you run this: `echo "Message-Authenticator = 0x00,FreeRADIUS-Statistics-Type = 31" | radclient localhost:18121 status adminsecret` ?

Comment: Sent Status-Server Id ... but no any output from Freeradius. hmmm...No reply from server for ID 175 socket 3

Comment: I've made tunneling with certs, how it would described here : https://www.ossramblings.com/RADIUS-3.X-Server-on-Ubuntu-14.04-for-WIFI-Auth

Comment: You have to have the status vhost enabled, so it is not entirely meaningful. Also see what happens running freeradius -X with  `echo "User-Name=test,User-Password=mypass,Framed-Protocol=PPP " | /usr/local/bin/radclient localhost:1812 auth secret` . If something shows, the problem is hostapd.

Comment: No trying to configure EAP-TLS, right? I would recommend putting it to work with EAP-TTLS or PEAP before going there, *if* that is the intention. I use at work a dual conf EAP-TTLS+PEAP with server certs. Try to keep working the lower functionalities, and only go to more complicate ones after you see the pieces are working together.

Comment: So, output from 'echo User-Name ...' is follows: Sent Access-Request Id 169 ... -> No reply from server for ID 169 socket 3

Comment: EAT-TLS would the same as in BLOG (Link) written configured

Comment: sorry: Reply verification failed: Received Access-Reject packet from home server...

Comment: something more: Shared secret is incorrect. Invalid Response Authenticator

Comment: Does it mean, problem with Certs?

Comment: FreeRadius is working then, good news. I guess you substituted your password for secret in clients.conf. you are expected to substitute it back for your password in any related commands you do.

Comment: Oh, ok, the same command, but with password from clients.cnf (before I tried from ca.cnf and server.cnf): Received Access-Reject: Expected Acces-Accept got Access-Reject

Comment: Freeradius is working...you must make sure the secret is also right in hostapd (same as clients.conf)

Comment: ok, thank you anyway, and I appreciate your help, unfortunately I cannot upvote your answer with my reputation, but only to say you THANK YOU! for your time and help. I will look one more time all my settings, cause secret is 100% the same (i've checked it)

Comment: If you still do not see anything with freeradius -X, after this debugging session, we at least are sure it is your hostapd that needs some change.

Comment: YES!!! Know, what I've changed? in hostapd.conf, as you said: it was ieee8021x set on 0, i've changed it to 1 (IEEE 802.1X Authorization). Now it works!I can see output from Freeradius and can check certificate of Freeradius by my client! Could you please edit your answer in this thread adding this line ieee8021x=1, then I can vote it as Right Answer!

Comment: It makes sense. I was right now about to double check my hostpad.conf here.